# Printing newline in TextBlock in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I want to assign the `TextBlock's Text` in my code behind and display it on the screen. It might contain `new line character` also. But somehow the `TextBlock` is not printing that character. I have used the following combinations in my text to print the new line character

- `&#x0A;`
- `&#x0D;&#x0A;`
- `&#10;`
- `&#13;&#10;`
- `\n`
- `\r\n`

Has anyone done this? can you help me?

Comment: are you setting it by code or XAML?

Comment: setting the text in the code behind `.cs`.

Comment: can you show me what have you set in code and how it is being displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `XAML` you can do like this

```
<TextBlock>Hello how are you?<LineBreak/>I'm fine</TextBlock>
```

In code you can do like this

```
textBlock.Text = "Hello how are you?\nI'm fine.";
```

Both are working for me.

---

**Edited**

For your scenario you can do this

```
string str = @"Hello how are you?\nI'm fine.";//This is your actual string containing \n as character
```

or in your case

```
string str = _arr[index];
str = str.Replace(@"\n", "\n");
```

Replace "\n" string with new line character.
**P.S.** It will create problem where you actually want to show `\n` string instead of new line character.

Comment: Doesn't help. As I said I want to set it in code and not in XAML

Comment: doesn't work. Already tried it. Displays `Hello how are you?\nI'm fine.` in the textblock

Comment: Text_full.Text = _arr[index];

_arr[index] for eg. is "Sachin\nSehwag"

Comment: for testing just create a new TextBlock `<TextBlock x:Name="tb_gogo"/>` in your xaml and set the text from the code `textBlock.Text = "Hello how are you?\nI'm fine.";` try it, I think it should work

Comment: Also Use `Debug.WriteLine(_arr[index]);` and see the output whether it prints new line or not?

Comment: Its working if I do that but acc do my pblm I have to read the text from the array which is getting populated from file on runtime. and in that case \n is not working

Comment: Also the text block is inside a scrollviewer if it helps. I guess the scrollviewer should not cause any problem.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. You are reading from the file and that file contain "\n" as `\\` and `n` two charters not new line character. For new line character it won't be visible in the file. Check your file and see if you can see `\n` characters instead of enter

Comment: Debugger is also printing it like Sachin\nSehwag. Whats the cause of this?

Comment: In the file I have manually types it as `\n` and it appears as `\n` in the file. So how do I fix it? If its reading it as `\``n`??

Comment: remove \n and just press enter there.

Comment: But that would affect all of my indexing. As every line = index in array.

Comment: I guess I should replace it after reading in the code with `\n`. Then it will be solved. Not even this is helping..

Comment: ha ha ha... then I think I should edit my answer again.. wait for a min

Comment: I replaced `\\n` with `\n` in the .cs and it worked. Thanks for the help. I guess you are right that its reading \n as two characters and not one from the file. Please add this to your answer so that anyone else who has the same problem can benefit from this :)